# Problem positioning window when using SetParent()

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, office-automation, setparent

I'm trying to set `childForm` as the child of the main Excel window using the SetParent API through PInvoke:

```
Form childForm = new MyForm();
IntPtr excelHandle = (IntPtr) excelApplication.Hwnd;
SetParent(childForm.Handle, excelHandle);
childForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
childForm.Left = 0;
childForm.Top = 0;
```

As you can see above, my intention is also to position the child in the top left corner of Excel window. However, for some reason the `childForm` always ends up at some weird location.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

While all answers here suggest perfectly logical approaches, none of them worked for me. Then I tried MoveWindow. For some reason I don't understand, it did the job.

Here's the code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

...

Form childForm = new MyForm();
IntPtr excelHandle = (IntPtr) excelApplication.Hwnd;
SetParent(childForm.Handle, excelHandle);
MoveWindow(childForm.Handle, 0, 0, childForm.Width, childForm.Height, true);
```

Comment: +1 This was the next thing I would have suggested to try. You're making an unmanaged API call to set the window's parent, so it's very likely that the routines employed by managed code to change the position of the window won't work property. I'm glad this fixed your problem, but you should still make sure the window styles (adding `WM_CHILD` and removing `WM_POPUP`) are set correctly, as I mentioned in my previous answer, to prevent any future problems and remain consistent with the documentation.

Comment: Yes Cody, I made sure I set those styles. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It saved my day.

Answer (score 7):

When using `SetParent` on a form that is currently a child of the desktop (in other words, one without a parent
set), you must set the `WS_CHILD` style and remove the `WS_POPUP` style. (See the Remarks section of the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633541%28VS.85%29.aspx) entry.) Windows requires that all owned windows have the `WS_CHILD` style set. This could also be causing the left and top properties to report/set the wrong values because the form doesn't know who it's daddy is. You can fix this by calling [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28VS.85%29.aspx) after `SetParent`, but before you try to set the location:

```
//Remove WS_POPUP style and add WS_CHILD style
const UInt32 WS_POPUP = 0x80000000;
const UInt32 WS_CHILD = 0x40000000;
int style = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE);
style = (style & ~(WS_POPUP)) | WS_CHILD;
SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your ShowDialog call I believe. If you call ShowDialog without the parent paremeter, the parent is reset.

You could create a wrapper class that implements IWin32Window and returns the HWND to excel. Then you could pass that to the ShowDialog call of childForm.

You could also query the position of the excel application using GetWindowPos and then set the childForm accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try a few things to diagnose the problem:

- Put a breakpoint after setting Left
  and Top, do Left and Top read zero?
- Call SetParent last.
- Make a method that sets Left and Top
  again, and BeginInvoke the method.
- Make sure your child window is really
  the child.  To do this call
  ShowDialog, and try to click the
  parent window.  Make sure windows
  prevents focus to the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to get the hwnds of the windows you want to set z-order of, you can use this pInvoke:

```
    public stati class WindowsApi 
    {
     [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
        int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
    }



    public class WindowZOrderPositioner 
    {
         public void SetZOrder(IntPtr targetHwnd, IntPtr insertAfter)
         {
             IntPtr nextHwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

             WindowsAPI.SetWindowPos(targetHwnd, insertAfter, 0, 0, 0, 0, SetWindowPosFlags.NoMove | SetWindowPosFlags.NoSize | SetWindowPosFlags.NoActivate);
     }
```