# Modal Dialog in child WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, modal-dialog

I have the following scenario in a multi-process C# WPF application:

MainApplication has a placeholder to contain child processes' HWNDs.

Using SetParent and some more windows functions (P/Invoke, Windows API) I can set child applications to live inside main application without letting the user know they are 2 processes.
Until now everything works good.

The problem is that every time I open a Modal Dialog from the child process, the modal dialog is actually not modal. Instead If I run the child application (same exe) standalone, the modal dialog works correctly.

Using Spy++ I realized that the owner of the modal dialog is the Desktop if running as a child process (not working as intended), or the correct application window, if running standalone (working as intended).

I also tried to use ::SetParent on the dialog, but nothing change, It seems that when the dialog is created from a hosted process, WPF can't set it's parent correctly.

Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: of course I tried to set dialog's owner using wpf methods (also WindowInteropHelper)

Comment: Yes, you're doing something wrong.  Using `SetParent` to host another process inside yours is a hack - a dirty awful hack with all kinds of nasty quirks, oddities, pitfalls, bugs, and potential for dozens of things to go wrong - wonky modal dialogs are just the tip of the iceberg.  Don't write applications like this - whatever your problem is, this is not the solution.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3045880/327083   This is delphi, not c#, but the principle remains the same.

Comment: Ok, so, how do multi-tab browser manage multiprocess windows?

Comment: Multitab browsers are still a single process.  They have multiple windows and are heavily multithreaded, but all windows and threads belong to the same process.

Comment: No, not Chrome for example. Chrome is multiprocess. A process per Tab. Or something like that

Comment: Ok, Chrome is a special exception.  To answer the "how do they do it" question is not straightforward at all.  I'm not saying that hosting multiple processes is impossible - it's just exceptionally difficult to get it to work right.  Chrome has a massive codebase to manage all of the nuances of those processes - very deep micromanagement of low level WinAPI, very careful error and exception handling, etc.

Comment: Further, Chrome is a special case where the hosted processes are all part of the controlled codebase and are written to *expect* to be hosted in a parent process.  This can't be said for almost any other random application you may try to graft into your own program.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2019500/327083  In almost any other conceivable situation it is usually highly advisable to seriously reconsider the architecture when faced with a desire to host one process inside another.

Comment: For example, other things to consider : http://stackoverflow.com/q/170800/327083  ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/4124025/327083  ; http://stackoverflow.com/q/3459874/327083

Comment: Even Jon Skeet says "be careful!" : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5191023/327083

Comment: For the record, IE is multi-process as well. It wouldn't surprise me to find most if not all browser vendors moving to such a design. But it _is_ complicated to implement; not for the faint of heart. You may require some inter-process negotiation to make sure all the windows cooperate with each other, including display dialogs modally. Things like Chrome and IE definitely are _not_ trying to run multiple processes that all are ignorant of each other.

Comment: I tried to study a little bit of Chromium architecture, which is open source and documented. Only one process manages UI, all the other ones are just calculation ones. So I think it's definitely not a good design, and if you can, you should avoid doing that.